# Как сделать блок изначальо закрытым

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(function(){
  $("button").click(function () {
      $("div").slideToggle("slow");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Вуаля!</button><br><br>
<div>
 <b>Правило.</b> Ё должна использоваться: в случаях возможных разночтений; в словарях; 
 в книгах для изучающих русский язык (т. е. детей и иностранцев); для правильного 
 прочтения редких топонимов, названий или фамилий. Во всех остальных случаях 
 наличие буквы ё только затрудняет чтение. Она плохо выглядит, зато хорошо звучит.
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы блок был изначально закрытым?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто добавить к `div`-блоку стиль, в котором описать свойство [display](http://htmlbook.ru/css/display), которое определяет, как элемент должен быть показан в документе:

```
<div style="display: none;">
```

Все это можно увидеть, если посмотреть в исходный код вашего документа и увидеть как он изменяется. Пример Вашего исходного кода до нажатия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

исходный код после нажатия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отсюда можно сделать простой вывод, чего Вам не хватает в коде.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(function(){
  $("button").click(function () {
      $("div").slideToggle("slow");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Вуаля!</button><br><br>
<div style="display: none;">
 <b>Правило.</b> Ё должна использоваться: в случаях возможных разночтений; в словарях; 
 в книгах для изучающих русский язык (т. е. детей и иностранцев); для правильного 
 прочтения редких топонимов, названий или фамилий. Во всех остальных случаях 
 наличие буквы ё только затрудняет чтение. Она плохо выглядит, зато хорошо звучит.
</div>
```